# Build a renaissance flying boat?

Tags: science-based, technology

What would be necessary for a boat to fly with renaissance technology?

Resources are unlimited! But this has to be science based. I imagine a steam engine + balloon hybrid or something.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can find "flying boats" which really consist of rubber rafts attached to Rogallo hang glider wings and a powerful engine driving the prop. The powerful engine driving the prop part is why heavier than air flying machines did not arrive until the 20th century.

Answer (score 1):

The only technology available was balloons, and even that was a century later (18th, while Renaissance was 14th through 17th).

You could have the development of ligher-than-air technology culumnanting in **airships** during the desired period, without straining plausibility for most readers. Come up with reasons for the accelerated development, such as war, and find real precursors that were not followed up at the time.

Comment: Seconded.  If there is a large enough advantage to be had from airships, you can bet a state actor will invest the time and money to make it happen.

Answer (score 1):

You'd start with the lightest weight boat they could think of. Maybe a a light framework covered with treated leather similar to the boats the Celts used.

Add fixed wings based on the work of daVinci did on studying the flight of birds. And realize these wings will allow flight if enough speed is generated.

Then realize that the windwheel of Heron of Alexandria can be used in reverse. That is it will create a wind if you make it rotate and that will make the boat move. daVinci's helicopter includes these realizations, so this is realistic enough.

Use Heron's aeolipile to generate the rotation. Generating  enough pressure to get useful level of power without adding lots of mass will be a major issue. And rapid consumption of both water and fuel would limit working duration to be very short. Aeolipile is still closest thing to a working steam engine light enough to be useful for a vehicle renaissance technology can build.

If the technical problems were solved the ground effect might allow this to lift off from water. And then rapidly crash as not even daVinci had any real idea of **controlling** flight. With wings that happened to be optimized for ground effect low level flight over calm water might be possible. The range would be very limited due to carried water being rapidly expelled as steam. Gathering the steam and reusing it as water would be too heavy. There is a reason that steam powered airships never really took off.

But this contraption might fly...